# Podio ephemeral ports?

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, acl, podio

TL;DR - What is the ephemeral ports that podio uses?..

We have a dotnet core application running in AWS interacting with podio. The Network Access Control List blocks off some of the responses from podio when podio responds on the ephemeral ports. I really dont want to add an inbound rule allowing all ports to communicate into our subnets, but event with a rule allowing 10000-65535, some responses are blocked.

- The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA) suggests the range 49152 to 65535.
- Many Linux kernels use the port range 32768 to 61000.

Answer (score 0):

Podio serves traffic over https server from standard port 443. Can you elaborate on what ephemeral usage of ports you have in mind?

Comment: When you send a request to podio it sends the response to your machine on some port. The question is what port range podio is expected to send the response on.